# How to package minimized JS files of an webapp in a debian package?

Tags: packaging, webapps

Usually JS files in Webapps are used in a minimized form (e.g. jquery.min.js), and lintian treats such files with very long lines as binaries. Usually these minimized JS files are not written by the developer of the webapp, but are external libraries (which are free softwares).

Debian developers suggest that these files should be not be kept in the minimized version in the Debian source package, and they should rather be compiled to the minimized version when the debian binary package is built (e.g. with `debuild`)

How to achieve this? Can `npm` be somehow used to do this?

Comment: Note: Although this question is related to submitting a package to debian repositories, this is not off-topic, because this is one of the recommended ways to get a software included in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, can achieve this.

1. Add minimizer lib to your build, few options

   - Like **[`babel-minify`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=babel-minify)** to build dependency of *Debian source package*, it is already in Ubuntu repository. In `debian/control`

     ```
     Build-Depends: ..., babel-minify
     ```
   - Put `npm` in the package build requirement. In `debian/control`

     ```
     Build-Depends: ..., npm
     ```

     Download `terser`, `minify` or any other tool using `npm`. But this may not possible on offline build machines. In build script if you have one or `debian/rules`.

     In `project.json`..[`"devDependencies":{}`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-json) .
2. Then used them to generate the minimized JS copies.

   In `project.json`.. put commands in [`"scripts":{}`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/scripts)

I would recommend a full build script at upstream source (Using JS specific way like `project.json`). Keep only special Debian processes in `debian/rules`.

For [`rules` (It is a Makefile)](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/dreq.en.html#rules), you can override any step, example:

```
override_dh_prep:
    ...
override_dh_auto_configure:
    ...
override_dh_auto_install:
    ...
```

Still there other ways for packaging if you are not using DebHelper. I'm not familiar with JS ecosystem

- https://wiki.debian.org/Javascript/Tutorial#Working_with_existing_packages
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-deb

Comment: How to configure debian/rules to do this?

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi Update my answer. There are many paths to package from npm to deb. I know Deb for compiled languages + python. It is always best to have a complete build script in upstream project before trying to make any workarounds at packaging level. If you can share more about your project (project.json, control, rules,*.install), I may able to help more specific.

Comment: The project I intend to package is [Foliate](https://github.com/johnfactotum/foliate/). It uses minified version of [JSZip](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/) and non-minified version of certain [other js libraries](https://github.com/johnfactotum/foliate/issues/530#issuecomment-658892997). Right now, there is a working debian package, but it is not upto the strict standards set by Debian.

Comment: I am accepting your answer. If I face any specific issue, I will ask another specific question about it (and I if you are okay with that, I will tag you by commenting to this answer)

Comment: No problem @ArchismanPanigrahi you welcome. I have checked the project and [the related bug report](https://github.com/johnfactotum/foliate/issues/530). It is using `meson` and `package.json` is not complete (have also [a bug report](https://github.com/johnfactotum/foliate/issues/460)).

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi Best to go `src/meson.build`, I think the team would accept to minify all libs for all releases to make it lighter. If they don't want additional dependency, make script robust by skipping minify step if its tool missing not pre-installed in the host. Or go with `debian/rules`:`override_dh_auto_install` for Debian package only.